# How to use Ajax to fetch data from database in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I would like to start by saying that i am completely new to Ajax so please bear with me. 
I have to calculate the sum of all the prices sold between the two dates taken as an input.

Here is my table

```
     Product_ID----ProductName------price------OrderDate
    ---  1  --------  Chair -------- 7 ------ 2015-01-05
    ---  2  --------  Lamp --------- 14 ----- 2015-01-16
    ---  3  --------  Table -------- 9 ------ 2015-02-25
```

Here's my HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showPrice(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getprice.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
 <input type="date" name="startdate">
 <p>To</p>
 <input type="date" name="enddate">
 <br><br>
 <button type="submit" name="submit"       
onclick="showAge(this.value)">Calculate</button>

</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Age  will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my MySQL query

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS TotalPrice 
FROM orders
WHERE OrderDate >= '11/11/2014' AND OrderDate <= '15/11/2015'
```

So my question is, how can i send two dates as input using ajax to calculate the sum of prices?

Comment: That query will not work.

Comment: What is your problem? What have you tried to do about it? Please improve your question by adding more info on the actual thing blocking you.

Comment: Database allow only Y-m-d date format so convert your Date accordingly

Comment: @SunilPachlangia, this query works since i have tested it.. I need to know how do i need to send two dates in a Ajax method to compute the sum of prices. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change this line to,

xmlhttp.open("GET","getprice.php?q="+str,true);

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getprice.php?q1="+str1+"&q2="+str2,true);
```

and str1 and str2 will be your both dates, 11/11/2014 & 15/11/2015. you must modify this date to Y-m-d format.

You can convert the date like this,

```
$date = '10.21.2011';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('.', '/', $date)));
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

```
var date1 = $('#startdate').val();
var date2 = $('#enddate').val();

    xmlhttp.open("GET","getprice.php?q1="+date11+"&q2="+date2,true);
```

then format date to `'Y-m-d'` and pass it to your query